# How to do this effect

Tags: ios, show-hide

I want to know how to do this effect:

When the user clicks the plus sign on the initial screen (see first screenshot), the list will drop down and plus sign change to minus sign (see seconds screenshot).

[image: Before]
<sub>(source: [store.qq.com](http://b223.photo.store.qq.com/psb?/V11ixOec0KfVzE/fJBNAGr5NKNwTnFR7sqIfQWS5qPgVfChmOvMY1g79WY!/b/YZ1h94QZPQAAYpra9YT1PAAA))</sub>

[image]

Comment: It looks like the pictures that you linked are being blocked.

Comment: I am unable to view the first picture; could you please upload it elsewhere?

Comment: The second picture does not load...

Comment: copy and paste guys, @user1506299 I'm unclear on what you're asking.  Do you want to change the button image after clicking it?  Or do you want to move the bottom view off the screen?

Comment: I suspect he wants to know how to expand/collapse the text using the +/- signs shown besides the title.

Comment: hi,  lvella, you are right. I want to know using the +/- to expand/collapse the text. Is this a iOS standard method(control), or others? Thank you.

Comment: This is not a standard control, and you'd have to do this yourself, but in the world of animation, this is a fairly easy one. See the animation section of the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own. E.g., here is a super simple example that shows you how to hide and show stuff. I'm not using a graphical +/- button (but rather a simple text button), but hopefully this gives you enough clues on how to do this properly yourself. This just demonstrates the animation that reveals the text panel (you can put graphics or whatever on this panel).

There are tons of ways to do this and this is overly simplistic, and clearly I haven't spent any time on the aesthetics, but hopefully it shows you some techniques you could use. I think the key trick is to put the stuff to be revealed onto a UIView on your main view, give it a height of zero, and then animate the changing of the frame to be expanded. You can also move buttons, change the UIImage you use for the buttoner, etc., but you get the idea.

```
//  SlideInViewController.m

#import "SlideInViewController.h"

@interface SlideInViewController ()
{
    UIView *_hiddenPanel;
    UIButton *_hideShowButton;
    BOOL _panelHidden;
}
@end

@implementation SlideInViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize the flag

    _panelHidden = YES;

    // create the panel that will be hidden initially (height of zero), but will be revealed when you click on the button

    _hiddenPanel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 300.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0)];
    _hiddenPanel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_hiddenPanel];

    // add the button

    _hideShowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    _hideShowButton.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 260.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    [_hideShowButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_hideShowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hideShowPanel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_hideShowButton];

    // now put whatever you want on this hidden panel.

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200.0)];
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.text = @"This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. This is a very long label. ";
    [_hiddenPanel addSubview:label];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)hideShowPanel:(id)sender
{
    if (_panelHidden)
    {
        // if the panel was already hidden, let's reveal it (and move/adjust the button accordingly)

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            _hideShowButton.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 60.0, 40.0, 40.0);
            [_hideShowButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            _hiddenPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200.0);
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // if the panel was already shown, so now let's hide it again (and move/adjust the button accordingly)
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            _hideShowButton.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 260.0, 40.0, 40.0);
            [_hideShowButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            _hiddenPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 300.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0);
        }];
    }

    _panelHidden = !_panelHidden;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thinks a lot. I will try this.